# How to use a custom image for cursor/thumb in html input type range

Tags: html, css

My element is a range-type slider bar

```
<input id="bar" type="range" min="0" max="72" value="0" onchange="updateValue(this.value);" />
```

For the cursor/thumb I do not want to use default image. 
I have to use my own .png image in my project folder.

Here's the current css for my thumb

```
input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  /*height: 38px;
  width: 1px;*/
  background: transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  cursor: default;
  border: initial;
  border-left: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #474747;
  -moz-appearance:none; /* Firefox */
  -webkit-appearance:none; /* Safari and Chrome */  
}
```

How can I provide my own custom image for the thumb ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.test {
    cursor:url("http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/cursor-hand.gif"), auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wNKcU/5/

Comment: Thanks, but what if I dont want to use any hyperlink. I just have the image in my folder at /images/pointer.png ?

Comment: @Ankit then just put the relative path from your css in place of his placeholder (e.g. `cursor:url("../images/pointer.png"), auto;`) If you still have problems using relative paths in css, I'd suggest searching for an answer or asking a new question, in the meantime you should accept Kar Reddy's answer.

Comment: This solution does not seem right to me. I understood that the question was on how to change the thumb to show a custom image, not how to change the cursor.